# Array rotation in python with given number of moves

Tags: python, python-3.x

given an array of length n with k rotation to perform.i have tried this but getting error

```
shifted = []
size , rotation = [int(size)for size in input().split()]
arr= [int(size) for size in input().split()]
for loop in range(len(arr)):
  indx = (loop+rotation)%len(arr)
  shifted[indx:indx] = arr[loop]

print(shifted)
```

i got this error:
    shifted[indx:indx] = arr[loop]
    TypeError: can only assign an iterable

Comment: What error are you getting please add it to the question

Comment: @devesh error  : TypeError: can only assign an iterable

Comment: `shifted[indx:indx]` is an empty list so fix that first

Comment: thanx @ Devesh for your input . but how to fix it i am not getting it please help..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming left rotation and input of:

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
k = 3
n = 10
```

If you don't need to do this in place you can do the following:

```
result = lst[k:] + lst[:k] # [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2]
```

`deque` is also an option:

```
from collections import deque
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
result = deque(lst)
result.rotate(-3) # Rotate 3 to the left
print(list(result))
```

Comment: @Remorse thanks for the input, i want left rotation. for ex my arr[1,2,3,4,5] and when performing 4 left rotation i should get [5,1,2,3,4]

Comment: @AjayKumarSinha `result` is a left rotation.

Comment: @Remorse yes thanx for this answer , but i didnt get the logic.

Comment: @AjayKumarSinha See update its cleaner. You just grab the last values after the first `k` values (`lst[k:]`) and put it before the first `k` values (`lst[:k]`)

Comment: @AjayKumarSinha I added a solution that may be easier to understand as well which uses `deque`.